# term for data that compares a day to same day of a week/month/year ago

Tags: terminology

What is the technical term for a report or dataset that compares data of an interval of time with that of the same interval in a previous week, month, or year?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study

Answer (score 1):

A repeated [cross-sectional study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-sectional_study). Cross-sectional refers to data collected at one specific point in time or over a short period. Repeated since you compare at least two time frames. If there are several time frames, one could talk about [time-series cross-sectional (TSCS)](http://as.nyu.edu/docs/IO/2576/beck.pdf) data. Repeated cross-sectional studies may become pseudolongitudinal, or [longitudinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study) if carried over a longer lapse of time.